# [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: php, mysql, html5, css3, docker

necesito ayuda con error informático que se presenta al levantar una imagen en Docker.

Tengo un macbook pro con el nuevo chip m1 pro de Apple y le instalé los siguientes programas: OpenVPN y Docker para levantar la imagen en localhost.

Esta imagen corresponde a un sistema (dashboard) que requiere usuario y contraseña para ingresar.

Todo el proceso iba bien, VPN activado y Docker iniciado, luego en el navegador la interfaz del login solicita usuario y contraseña. Se ingresan los datos, pero al hacer clic en el botón acceder, el navegador intenta cargar el dashboard y arroja el siguiente mensaje:

[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Comment: bueno parece que la imagen de docker necesita algun parametro hacia una base de datos de access por el componente odbc que no se encuentra en la imagen de docker